# Slow memcached working

Tags: mysql, apache, memcached

I  have prestashop  with memcached. But speed creating page with memcached slower  then without memcached. 
without -0.9 sec , with memcached about 1.2 sec :(

Memcahced stats

1) [Stats Picture [image: stats picture]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs5YA.jpg)

2) [Server atop picture [image: server atop picture]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxLn3.jpg)

STAT maxbytes 1098907648
STAT maxconns 1024
STAT tcpport 11211
STAT udpport 11211
STAT inter NULL
STAT verbosity 0
STAT oldest 0
STAT evictions on
STAT domain_socket NULL
STAT umask 700
STAT growth_factor 1.25
STAT chunk_size 48
STAT num_threads 4
STAT num_threads_per_udp 4
STAT stat_key_prefix :
STAT detail_enabled no
STAT reqs_per_event 20
STAT cas_enabled yes
STAT tcp_backlog 1024
STAT binding_protocol auto-negotiate
STAT auth_enabled_sasl no
STAT item_size_max 2097152
STAT maxconns_fast no
STAT hashpower_init 0
STAT slab_reassign no
STAT slab_automove 0
STAT lru_crawler no
STAT lru_crawler_sleep 100
STAT lru_crawler_tocrawl 0
STAT tail_repair_time 0
STAT flush_enabled yes
STAT hash_algorithm jenkins

Comment: Please prefer copy/paste the text over screen capture.

Comment: excuse me? text of config?